# Index Match Partial Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to Index/Match a column with shortened criteria. The idea is to Pull the Line of Business from the column without producing dozens of "duplicate" Unique Lines of Business.

Currently, I get a list like:

[image: First List]

Whereas I just want:

[image: Second List]

I don't want to use a fixed list lookup, as the data is varied enough to not be practical using a fixed list

The ARRAY formula so far: `{=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$155,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($Q$156:Q156,$C$1:$C$155)+COUNTIF($C$1:$C$155,$C$1:$C$155<>1),0)),"")}`

Is there a way to search in the text for the company name without creating a new column?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use some sort of formula like this to filter your countif query `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("company",A1)),"Company "&MID(A1,FIND("company",A1)+8,1),"")`.

This code searches your list for the word company and then outputs the word "Company" then searches 8 positions to the right from the start of the word and returns the number.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified, I was just using placeholders. I'll edit my question.

Comment: The question is quite a bit more complicated now with that data. You will most likely need to use some VBA code to get the output you want without having several helper columns. Unfortunately I do not have much experience in VBA scripting.